# integration using partial fractions instead of u substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I had a question in a maths exam today, that I was quite annoyed at myself for not being able to solve. It was, I thought, a relatively simple integration problem.

$$\int \frac{8}{x^2-4} dx$$

Now I used u substitution, setting $u = x^2-4$ and therefore $\frac{du}{dx}=2x$

$$8\int \frac{1}{u}du = 8 ln|u|$$

Substituting back in for u, my final answer was:
$$\frac{2ln|x^2-4|}{x}+c$$
After I left the exam, I used WolframAlpha to calculate the integral, the solution being:
$$-2ln|x+2|+2ln|x-2|+c$$
I can now do this, using partial fractions and get the correct answer. The only thing that concerns me is that I do not know why it doesn't work using u substitution. If anyone could please explain why, it would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I'm new on this site, so please don't be too mad if I've committed some cardinal sin in this post thanks.

Comment: You forgot $du=2xdx \neq dx$

Comment: I've used it in working out my answer, I just didn't include it in the steps I took. Have I done something wrong with the u substitution?

Comment: I believe your u-sub was faulty.  It's best to use $u=x^2\pm c$ substitution when there is a free $x$ somewhere in the integrand.  As you showed, $\frac{du}{dx}=2x$ and so $du=2xdx$.  You need to use this fact when changing variables; that $du$ in your second integral can't come from nowhere

Comment: Ahh, thank you. Turns out I've been doing u substitution wrong this entire time.

Comment: Actually, just a quick one Jason, does that mean that this problem just can't be solved with u substitution at all?

Comment: $u$ substitution can be tried but it won't do you much help.

Comment: It can, but it is a bit more complicated. You can substitute $x = -2 \tanh \left(\frac{u}{4}\right)$ where $\tanh$ is the hyperbolic tangent. If you are careful and use some identities of hyperbolic functions the integral becomes really easy.

Comment: @TomBailey Yeah, u-sub is not the way to solve it.  Yeah be careful with obtaining your $du$.  You couldn't u-sub on this problem, but if there was an $x$ in the numerator, you could (even then, partial fractions might still be better)

Comment: You can probably do it using $x=2\sec u$, $dx=2\sec \tan u\,du$, but partial fractions will be easier.